# How to retrieve a part of packed binary in PHP?

Tags: php, binary

I have that packed data:

```
$binarydata = pack("C*", ...$chunk);
```

I know that header is from [1..189] of that $binarydata
equivalent in nodeJs:

```
var bufferHeader = Buffer.from(data, 1, 189)
```

How do I retrieve that part from `$binarydata` ?

Answer (score 0):

[`substr()`](https://php.net/substr) can perform this operation on binary strings.

```
$binarydata = pack("C*", ...$chunk);
$bufferHeader = substr($binarydata, 1, 189); // offset, length
```

Here is a quick example :

```
$chunk = [0, 12, 34, 0, 56, 100, 128, 200, 225, 255];
$binarydata = pack("C*", ...$chunk);

// extract header 
$header = substr($binarydata, 2, 4);
print_r(unpack("C*",$header));
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [1] => 34
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 56
    [4] => 100
)
```

[live demo](https://3v4l.org/Zdd0h)

Comment: Does it answer your question ?